# How to test Yeoman frontend against (Spring) Backend?

Tags: angularjs, spring, frontend, yeoman, backend

I have a yeoman web-application with AngularJS which works great! Now I want to do some Ajax request to the backend.

The yeoman application runs on localhost:9000 (I run it with `grunt serve` which gives me fast live reloads)

The backend spring application runs on localhost:8080 (I run this with `mvn spring-boot:run`)

What is the workflow for testing the frontend with the backend? 
I can always copy the frontends build code to the backends public folder but its time consuming. Or I could do some cross domain Ajax attempts but not sure this is the right way to go either.

What is the fastest and easiest way to integrate the frontend with the backends API for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Ajax cross-domain issue with `proxy_pass`.
Just set a virtualhost for your frontend, and add a proxy_pass to your backend.

In case you are using Nginx (Apache also support proxy_pass):
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

In your virtualhost file it should be something like this:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
}
```

Comment: Ah okey, thank you! do you know if this is the recommended workflow?

Comment: @nilsi, that's what were using in our company. and it's the cleanest solution to the cross-domain issue I am familiar with.

Comment: @nilsi, you could also allow CORS on your backend by IP. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". but I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

it could be done with CORS managment like here:
[Spring Cors doc](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

or

use grunt proxy, in your gruntfile.js add this after connect: markup (suppose backend runing on localhost:9292)

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
    server: {
        proxies: [
            {
                context: '/',
                host: 'localhost:9292',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
```

see here http://fettblog.eu/blog/2013/09/20/using-grunt-connect-proxy/